# React.js gif is not loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a common use case to load a spinner in the component. This is my folder structure.

```
src
 /components
  /table
   -Table.js
   -Spinner.js
```

I import spinner like this

```
 const spinner = require('./spinner.gif');
```

When I console log spinner I got this

[image]

And call that in the component like this

```
<img src={spinner} alt='Data is loading...' />
```

But gif image is not loading. Instead I am getting the alt text.

How do I fix this with React?

Answer (score 0):

[My answer follows the documentation on webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css)

In your folder add a package for image loader
`npm install --save-dev file-loader`

Then change your `webpack.config.js` or any other named config file as below.

```js
 const path = require('path');

  module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
          ],
        },
        // Added below -----------
       {
         test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
         use: [
           'file-loader',
         ],
       },
       // Added above ---------------
      ],
    },
  };
```

Then you can import images as usual by doing

```js
 import image from './image.gif';
```

Or

```js
const image = require('./image.gif')
```